# Cannot replicate textbook derivation of simple algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm following a derivation for the expression of variable $b_2$:

[image]

But I'm not sure how combining (4.42) with (4.43) yields that expression for $b_2$. If I substitute $b_1=\frac{v_1}{v_2}b_2$ into the RHS of 4.41, I get

$$v_2\alpha \frac{(\frac{v_1}{v_2})^\alpha b_2^{\alpha-1}}{((\frac{v_1}{v_2})^\alpha b_2^\alpha+b_2^\alpha)^2}$$

and not the expression 4.43. Any ideas?

Comment: Your equation is slightly off- you're missing a $b_2^\alpha$ term in the numerator. Then just factor, cancel, and you have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $b_1=\frac{v_1}{v_2}b_2$ to second equation of $(4.41)$, we have

\begin{align}
1=v_2\alpha\cdot\frac{b_1^\alpha b_2^{\alpha-1}}{(b_1^\alpha+b_2^\alpha)^2}
&=v_2\alpha\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}b_2\right)^\alpha b_2^{\alpha-1}}{\left(\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}b_2\right)^\alpha+b_2^\alpha\right)^2}\\
&=v_2\alpha\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha b_2^{2\alpha-1}}{b_2^{2\alpha}\left[\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha+1\right]^2}\\
&=v_2\alpha\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha }{b_2\left[\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha+1\right]^2}
\end{align}
$$\implies b_2=v_2\alpha\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha }{\left[\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^\alpha+1\right]^2}$$

Comment: That's what I did. See my attempt.